# Error when installing tailwindcss-elevation

Tags: node.js, npm, tailwind-css

I'm trying to install a bunch of npm packages in my root test_project but I'm having dependency errors.

**Here's what I've done before producing errors:**

`npm init -y`

`npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest`

`npm install -D postcss-import@latest sass-loader@latest`

`npm install -D @tailwindcss/aspect-ratio @tailwindcss/line-clamp`

`npm install -D @tailwindcss/typography @tailwindcss/forms`

`npm install -D tailwindcss-gradients`

**Here's the problem:**

`npm install -D tailwindcss-elevation`

**and this is the error message:**

`ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree`

`npm ERR! While resolving: mongodb-and-php@1.0.0`

`npm ERR! Found: tailwindcss@3.0.23`

`npm ERR! node_modules/tailwindcss`

`npm ERR!   dev tailwindcss@"^3.0.23" from the root project`

`npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:`

`npm ERR! peer tailwindcss@"^2.0.1" from tailwindcss-elevation@1.0.1`

`npm ERR! node_modules/tailwindcss-elevation`

`npm ERR!   dev tailwindcss-elevation@"1.0.1" from the root project`

`npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry`

`npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps`

`npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.`

Could anyone explain why is this happening? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It means `tailwindcss-elevation` depends on `tailwindcss@"^2.0.1"`. But there is `tailwindcss@"^3.0.23"` in your project. So there is a conflict.

Comment: okay thanks, ill try to downgrade my version of tailwindcss to 2.0.1.